# Angular way to do an Element Directive animation when Object is deleted?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

I'm rendering an *scoped* Array of Objects(**payments** in this case), and passing each one to a **payment** Directive like this:

```
<div id="payable" ng-controller="PaymentsController">
  <payment ng-repeat="payment in payments" data="payment" class="payment"></payment>
</div>
```

This works really well! So when I delete an element from the *scoped* Array from the controller like this:

```
app.controller('PaymentsController', function($scope) {
  //The Payments Array(each object passed to a Directive)
  $scope.payments = [ { id: 1, amount: 10 }, { id: 2, amount: 15 } ]; 

  $scope.deletePayment = function(index) {
    //This deletes the Array Element and removes associated
    //Directive template from the DOM
    $scope.payments.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

`The CSS (uses compass mixins for simplicity)`

```
.payment.ng-enter {
  @include transition(all 2s ease-out);
  opacity: 0;
}

.payment.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.payment.ng-leave {
  @include transition(all 2s ease-out);
}

.payment.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Again, the above works as expected, I delete an element from the *payments* Array and the **directive-template/view** corresponding to the deleted Array element is removed from the DOM, This is PERFECT, except for the fact it's removed instantly!

**EDIT:**
The reason the animations like fadeOut don't work and the result is that the ( < payment > ) is removed instantly(after a specified time in the CSS) is that the animation is acting over the ( < payment >) custom tag, **which is just a wrapper for the actual element**.

`Directive JS definition:`

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('paymentDirectives', []);

  app.directive('payment', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        payment: '=data'  
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/payment.html'
    };
  });

})();
```

**The animation should act on the template referenced/wrapped by the directive custom tag( < payment > )**

`partials/payment.html`

```
<div class="a-payment">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      <label><a href="/#" class="important">{{payment.amount}}</a></label>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*In this case it would be the div with class="a-payment" of course* and when the animation is complete **it should then remove the payment tag element**

What is the Angular way(for the latest version) to do an animation for this case(ie. Element Directive is removed from the DOM)?

Thank you very much in advance, and let me know if you need more from the code I'm using.

Comment: You can fade out the div first and then remove the content from payments. I found this animation http://jsfiddle.net/angularjs_de/6VErN/

Comment: Cool, but the example isn't using a custom directive. :( The idea is to apply animations to the <payment> tag and have it behave like a regular HTML tag (ie, <div>, <p>, etc)

Comment: It's not to do with the fact that most custom tags, such as your `<payment>`, are `display: inline;` by default, is it? Are you setting their style to be `display: block` in the CSS/SASS?

Comment: @GregL. THAT WAS IT! Absolutely spot on!

Comment: @JoseE Okay, added as an answer then.

Comment: That's what happens when you're too lazy to show me your CSS after I've asked you twice...

Comment: Sorry, sir. The CSS was posted yesterday into the Question's edit. And that's all the CSS I used. apologies nonetheless, your answer was great, but since @GregL nailed the real problem immediately, he deserves to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to do with the fact that most custom tags, such as your `<payment>`, are `display: inline;` by default.

You should set their style to be `display: block` in the CSS/SASS.

Comment: Yes, sir. This is the correct answer, while for some cases display: block is not needed, it's obviously needed in my case. I have no idea why.

Comment: Unfortunately it's tricky when you want it to start "display: none" in this case as well.  What I had to do to make this start hidden was to CSS: `display: block`, but the directive link function `$(element).hide()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways, for example, you can create a class that will trigger the CSS animation, and before deleting the object, you first assign it that class. Here's how:

```
  var deleteAnimDuration = 1000; // let's use one second for our example

  $scope.deletePayment = function(index) {
    //This deletes the Array Element and removes associated
    //Directive template from the DOM
    $scope.payments[index].deleteAnim = true; // or whatever property makes sense to you
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.payments.splice(index, 1);
    }, deleteAnimDuration);
  }
```

Then on the directive, you can use `ng-class`:

```
<payment 
    ng-repeat="payment in payments" 
    data="payment" 
    ng-class="{deleting: payment.deleteAnim}">
</payment>
```

Then in the CSS:

```
payment.deleting {
    transition: opacity 1s linear; // again, one second
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Since this sample animation (opacity fade) will run for one second, you need to set `deleteAnimDuration` for the `$timeout` to one second (1000 in milliseconds).

So, what happens:

- you click delete on a payment
- it sets `payment.deleteAnim` to true, which assigns the `deleting` class to the element
- the timeout for the animation duration is set
- animation starts
- animation ends
- element removed from the DOM

This is the concept from the DOM standpoint:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.className = 'deleting';
    deleteEl(this)
  })
}

function deleteEl(el) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.deleting {
        transition: opacity 1s linear;
        opacity: 0;
    }

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  }
```

```html
<div>Click me</div>
<div>Click me</div>
<div>Click me</div>
<div>Click me</div>
```

---

Of course, this can work with JS animations as well.

Comment: Hello there! This is a really comprehensive answer, and the logic you propose is perfect (there's really no other way to describe it), however, it doesn't work because the target of the animation is the <payment> custom directive, and not the referenced template. So the result is that given that the <payment> tag is faded-out... once it completes it will remove its internal template instantly!
Your runnable example works perfectly because it's applying animation on 'regular' HTML tags directly. Try it on a Directive, refer to my Question updates for more info. And thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Well, if that's the case, you can easily modify the code to work with, say `.a-payment` elements or whatever element needs to fade out. But I don't get it, you say you have `<payment>other stuff/tags here</payment>` and that the payment element fades, but its contents remain unfaded until they are removed?

Comment: EXACTLY! it's because the <payment> 'wrapper' doesn't 'wrap' its contents. If you inspect the element using Dev Tools, you can see that the structure is correct HTML-wise, but the <payment> element itself NEVER acquires any height at all, hence the animation never 'acts' on its contents.

Comment: Oh, that changes things, but the principle remains the same. You just need to reference the right element in the click event handler. Can you make a quick working example? I'd like to see it.

Comment: Once again, you're right! it can be done that way, and your original answer would be ideal for example, but it does feel a little hack-ish, and not the angular way. The main problem I SEE, is that.. ok, you animate(fadeOut) the contents DIV, that's fine, but then you should also delete the parent element (ie. the <payment> tag) that's bound to the element in the payments array. it's 3 tasks that need to be chained together, right? I felt angular would have an easy way to do this very-common use case.

Comment: A wrapper not actually wrapping its contents is what's bothering me here. That's why I said I'd like to see it in action and that's why it has to look hackish. Can you at least recreate the HTML/CSS part of it?

Comment: All the code needed to recreate it is pretty much in my question now, I'd make a Fiddle out of it, but I've never really used it... I have trouble referencing ext. files like the Directive's template... feel free to try it on your own. Don't mean to be lazy, it just takes me too long to do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Load `angular-animate.min.js` in your HTML.
2. Add `ngAnimate` into your module dependencies.
3. Add a class to your payment directive element: e.g. `<payment class="my-animation" ...></payment>`.
4. Add the following CSS (referencing your class in step 3):

   `.my-animation.ng-leave { opacity: 1; transition: opacity 300ms linear; }`

   `.my-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 300ms linear; }`
5. Celebrate

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. In a nutshell this doesn't work because this isn't a regular HTML tag, this is a Custom Directive that 'wraps' a template(via templateUrl), and while your answer is of course the obvious one(after reading the docs), the result is that instead of having a fadeout, the element disappears instantly after the specified time. And this is 'expected' because the animation occurs on the <payment> custom tag and not inside its contained element(s).

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's a custom directive, and there are no real differences between a "regular" HTML tag and a custom directive tag. Here is a plunker to demonstrate your exact use case: http://plnkr.co/edit/srkefqaNIvDhcdxSf5qc?p=preview

Comment: You're absolutely right, it has nothing to do with it being a custom directive, like a commenter mentioned, it was only about the default display value. I set it to block and everything started to work well. If you want, you can add that into your answer and I'll set it as accepted answer.

Comment: No, as you can observe from my example, it does not require to be ```display: block```. It works fine for inline. Please double-check.

Comment: Thank you, I can see it works well in your example, AND HUGE THANKS for making a Plunkr out of my code!, but I can assure you, for my local code it'll only work if I include the display:block property.